# Show that: $(E^{\circ})^{\circ}=E^{\circ}$ i.e. the interior of the interior of a set equals the interior of the set.

Tags: general-topology

Let $(M,d)$ be a metric space. Show that $(E^{\circ})^{\circ}=E^{\circ}$.

I know that $A=A^{\circ}\Leftrightarrow A \text{ is an open set}$

So I want to prove that $E^{\circ}$ is an open set and then conclude that $(E^{\circ})^{\circ}=E^{\circ}$.

How do I prove that $E^{\circ}$ is an open set?

Or is there a simpler approach to this question?

Thanks.

Comment: There are several ways of defining the interior of a set; what definition are you working from?

Comment: **Hint:** What does it means $x\in E^\circ$.  What does it means $x\in (E^\circ)^\circ$.  Are there equivalent?

Comment: $x\in E^{\circ}\$ if $\exists$ $r=r(x)$ s.t.  $B_{r}(x)\subseteq E$ where $B_{r}(x)$ is the ball of radius $r$ centered in $x$

Comment: sorry I failed editing my comment within 5 minutes, what I meant is $x\in E^{\circ}\ \text{ if } \exists r=r(x)\text{ s.t.  }B_{r}(x)\subseteq E$, where $B_{r}(x)$ is the ball of radius $r$ centered in $x$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your definition of $E^\circ$ will affect your proof that $E^\circ$ is open. One may define $$E^\circ=\bigcup\{O:O\subset E\text{ and } O \text{ is open }\}$$

That is, $E^\circ$ is the largest *open* set contained in $E$, for the union of open sets is open.

If you define $$E^\circ=\{x:x \text{ is an interior point of E}\}$$

The observe that if $x\in E^\circ$ then there is an open set $O$ such that $x\in O\subseteq E$. But if $y\in O$ then $O$ itself is an open set such that $y\in O\subseteq E$, i.e $y\in E^\circ$. Thus for any $x\in E^\circ$ there is an open set $O$ such that $x\in O\subseteq E^\circ$, and $E^\circ$ is open.